# How can I have a custom XML file in modules merged as one in Magento 2? (MageStackDay mystery question 2)

Tags: configuration, xml, magento2, magento2-dev-beta

*MageStackDay bonus question for 500pts Bounty AND a the possibility of winning a free Z-Ray license for a year. More info can be found >> [here](http://magestackday.com/bountyhunt/) <<*

*The questions are provided/inspired by Magento 2 core developer Anton Kril.*

**Question:**

I'm creating an extension that has a separate set of configurations.
This means I cannot use `config.xml` or `routes.xml` or `fieldset.xml` or any other config xml files magento has.
Example.

Let's say I'm defining a 'table' config that has rows an columns. I could use this xml below.  (call it `table.xml`)

```
<table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="path/to/table.xsd">
    <row id="row1">
        <column id="col1" sort="10" attr1="val1">
            <label>Col 1</label>
        </column>
    </row>
    <row id="row2">
        <column id="col1" sort="10" attr1="val1">
            <label>Col 1</label>
        </column>
        <column id="col2" sort="20" disabled="true" attr1="val2" >
            <label>Col 2</label>
        </column>
        <column id="col3" sort="15" attr1="val1">
            <label>Col 3</label>
        </column>
    </row>
</table>
```

But if an other extension contains `table.xml` I want it to be picked up by the config reader and the 2 or more xml files should be merged. I mean if the second file looks like this

```
<table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="path/to/table.xsd">
    <row id="row1">
        <column id="col2" sort="10" attr1="val2">
            <label>Col 2</label>
        </column>
    </row>
    <row id="row2">
        <column id="col1" sort="10" attr1="val5" />
    </row>
</table>
```

the result will be that the second column is added to the first row and the value for `attr1` is overwritten by the second xml:

```
<table ....>
    <row id="row1">
        <column id="col1" sort="10" attr1="val1"> <!-- from first xml -->
            <label>Col 1</label>
        </column>
        <column id="col2" sort="10" attr1="val2"><!-- from second xml-->
            <label>Col 2</label>
        </column>
    </row>
    <row id="row2">
        <column id="col1" sort="10" attr1="val5"><!--they apear in both xmls with the same path and id and second one overrides the value for `attr1`-->
            <label>Col 1</label>
        </column>
        <column id="col2" sort="20" disabled="true" attr1="val2"><!-- from first xml -->
            <label>Col 2</label>
        </column>
        <column id="col3" sort="15" attr1="val1"><!-- from first xml -->
            <label>Col 3</label>
        </column>
    </row>
</table>
```

In Magento 1 I could have done this just by calling

```
 $merged = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('table.xml')
            ->applyExtends();
```

How can I do the same for Magento 2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Magento 2 this is handled by the `\Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem` class. This class allows you specify the xml file you want to merge.

The following part will merge all files found in the available modules and merge the output (snippet from `\Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem`)

```
/**
 * Load configuration scope
 *
 * @param string|null $scope
 * @return array
 */
public function read($scope = null)
{
    $scope = $scope ?: $this->_defaultScope;
    $fileList = $this->_fileResolver->get($this->_fileName, $scope);
    if (!count($fileList)) {
        return [];
    }
    $output = $this->_readFiles($fileList);

    return $output;
}

/**
 * Read configuration files
 *
 * @param array $fileList
 * @return array
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception
 */
protected function _readFiles($fileList)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom $configMerger */
    $configMerger = null;
    foreach ($fileList as $key => $content) {
        try {
            if (!$configMerger) {
                $configMerger = $this->_createConfigMerger($this->_domDocumentClass, $content);
            } else {
                $configMerger->merge($content);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception("Invalid XML in file " . $key . ":\n" . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    if ($this->_isValidated) {
        $errors = [];
        if ($configMerger && !$configMerger->validate($this->_schemaFile, $errors)) {
            $message = "Invalid Document \n";
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception($message . implode("\n", $errors));
        }
    }

    $output = [];
    if ($configMerger) {
        $output = $this->_converter->convert($configMerger->getDom());
    }
    return $output;
}
```

In the solution I created the class above is extended to supply the xml file needed and specify where the xsd file to validate can be found (see https://github.com/Genmato/MageStackTable for complete example):

```
namespace Genmato\TableXml\Model\Table;

class Reader extends \Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem
{
    protected $_idAttributes = [
        '/table/row' => 'id',
        '/table/row/column' => 'id',
    ];

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Config\FileResolverInterface $fileResolver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Config\ConverterInterface $converter
     * @param \Genmato\TableXml\Model\Table\SchemaLocator $schemaLocator
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Config\ValidationStateInterface $validationState
     * @param string $fileName
     * @param array $idAttributes
     * @param string $domDocumentClass
     * @param string $defaultScope
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Config\FileResolverInterface $fileResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Config\ConverterInterface $converter,
        \Genmato\TableXml\Model\Table\SchemaLocator $schemaLocator,
        \Magento\Framework\Config\ValidationStateInterface $validationState,
        $fileName = 'table.xml',
        $idAttributes = [],
        $domDocumentClass = 'Magento\Framework\Config\Dom',
        $defaultScope = 'global'
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $fileResolver,
            $converter,
            $schemaLocator,
            $validationState,
            $fileName,
            $idAttributes,
            $domDocumentClass,
            $defaultScope
        );
    }
```

To get the merged data you can then call:

```
$output = $this->_objectManager->get('Genmato\TableXml\Model\Table\Reader')->read();
```

The output is then an array representation of the merged xml.

**EDIT:**

To test the way the files are read I created a working example (see https://github.com/Genmato/MageStackTable). Updated the answer with the solution build.

Comment: Vladimir, earlier today I saw your previous answer version with `Dom` class example. I started working on answer utilizing `Reader` class. In the meantime I refreshed question page and realized you did that :-) +1

Comment: Thanks for the full detailed answer and for the POC module from github. Please leave it there for future references. Here...have some bounty.

Comment: Marius, Thanks! Will leave the module available on GitHub.